# Value converter vs Attached property

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

In case of long lines in xaml with bool to visibility converters I find this question interesting. What will do the job better: value converter or attached property?

Using value converter from bool to Visibility:

```
Visibility="{Binding IsCommentPreviewVisible,Converter={StaticResource myBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

or using attached property:

```
ap:BoolVisibility.Visible="{Binding IsCommentPreviewVisible}"
```

where `VisibleChanged` internally handle `Visibility` of `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: Note that the attached property only works because Visibility is defined so high up in the class diagram. Consider for instance a control with a LabelVisibility . How many attached properties is maintainable?

Comment: Sure, but in general, what will be faster/better in case of performance/memory/number of calls etc.

Comment: Unlikely to make any noticeable difference. I would consider this purely on readability and maintainability.

Comment: @crea7or If implemented properly, you can make them approximately the same speed. However, I would go with the second one, because it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Custom attached properties are generally good for when you need to set a property for a class other than the defining class.

Take `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top`, `Canvas.Right`, `Canvas.Bottom` for example, these properties are for the *parent* element to use, not specifically for the defining element. You would use `Canvas.` attached properties to define the positioning of elements **within** another element (a `Canvas`).

It might be worth reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.100).aspx).

Converters on the other hand offer you the means of quite simply, **converting** one data type to another on the UI. That being said, you can still use an **attached property** to mimic the behaviour of a converter.

If you need to do anything **culture aware** then an `IValueConverter` has this built in, an attached property does not. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Personally I tend to steer away from attached properties unless I need to *attach* a property which a parent class will need to use. It's difficult to provide a real example because I rarely use them, if ever.